# Tmap: How make tm_bubbles ouput into a range in legend?

Tags: r

My current tm_bubble looks like this in the legend:

[image: legend]

I used this code to get it:

```
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("plot")
v2<-tm_shape(map)+
  tm_polygons("Construction", palette= "Reds",
              colorNA="white",
              showNA=FALSE)+
  tm_shape(map)+
  tm_bubbles(size="Labour",col="black")+
  tm_shape(map)+
  tm_bubbles(size="Capital",col="grey")+
  tm_shape(worldmap2) +
  tm_borders(col = "grey",lwd = 0.5)+
  tm_layout(bg.color = "white")+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE,outer.margins=c(.05,0,.05,0), inner.margins=c(0,0,.02,0), asp=0,
           legend.outside=TRUE,
           legend.position=c("center","bottom"),
           title.position = c('center','top'))
v2
```

How do I make sure that the legend shows up in ranges instead of what is pictured?

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "show up in ranges"? Is what you have shown not a range? For me, it's a range from 2 to 10.

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1. i made changes to the question to add what I was looking for. Hope it answers your question.